# Exception occured during using python 64bit win32com (Solidworks-API): Exception SldWorks.Application.InvokeTypes

Tags: python, 64-bit, win32com, solidworks

I have on my Windows Server 2003, Standard x64 Edition a 64 bit Python 2.7 (python-2.7.3.amd64.msi) and a 64 bit win32-Extension (pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7.exe).
My Application is SolidWorks 2012 x64 Edition.
Then I generate with

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py "D:\Program Files\SolidWorks Corp\SolidWorks\sldworks.tlb" the file 83A33D31-27C5-11CE-BFD4-00400513BB57x0x20x0.py
```

and with

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py "D:\Program Files\SolidWorks Corp\SolidWorks\swconst.tlb" the file 4687F359-55D0-4CD3-B6CF-2EB42C11F989x0x20x0.py
```

My following code works fine on 32 bit Windowes XP with 32bit Python 2.4 and 32 bit win32-Extension.
But on my 64 bit server I get an exception "SldWorks.Application.InvokeTypes" by call ExitApp()-method.
What is the reason and how can I resolve this problem?
Thanks for your hints, Thomas

```
 try:

        pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)

        sldworks = gencache.EnsureModule('{83A33D31-27C5-11CE-BFD4-00400513BB57}', 0x0, 20, 0) 
        print "sldworks = " + str(sldworks)       
        swconst = gencache.EnsureModule('{4687F359-55D0-4CD3-B6CF-2EB42C11F989}', 0x0, 20, 0) 
        print "swconst = " + str(swconst)   


        sw = sldworks.ISldWorks(DispatchEx('SldWorks.Application'))  
        print "sw = " + str(sw)   

        sw.ExitApp() 

    except Exception, value:        
        print "Exception occured, value = ", value
```

here the prints:

```
sldworks = module 'win32com.gen_py.83A33D31-27C5-11CE-BFD4-00400513BB57x0x20x0' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\83A33D31-27C5-11CE-BFD4-00400513BB57x0x20x0.pyc'  

swconst = module 'win32com.gen_py.4687F359-55D0-4CD3-B6CF-2EB42C11F989x0x20x0' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\4687F359-55D0-4CD3-B6CF-2EB42C11F989x0x20x0.pyc'        

sw = win32com.gen_py.SldWorks 2012 Type Library.ISldWorks instance at 0x82548360  

Exception occured, value = SldWorks.Application.InvokeTypes
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
sw = win32com.client.Dispatch("SldWorks.Application")
```

instead

```
sw = sldworks.ISldWorks(DispatchEx('SldWorks.Application'))
```

and
with Python 2.4 32bit and win32 extension 32bit
it works fines.

Thomas

Diesen Beitrag melden Beitrag löschen